# Trying to use squeezelite with existing PulseAudio outputs

Tags: sound, 16.04, pulseaudio, alsa

So I am trying to set up a squeezebox (Logitech media server) client using squeezelite on my Ubuntu 16.04 install, and am having some trouble getting what I want out of it.

**What I am trying to achieve**

I want to be able to be playing music on my desktop through my headphones, and be able to open up the sound menu to switch the output to the computer's external speakers.

**What is actually happening**

When squeezelite is running, the sound menu does not show the built-in audio options (which includes the external speakers which are connected with aux), and sending audio to my computer from the server plays through the external speakers. When I kill squeezelite, the audio outputs reappear in the sound menu.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated, even if you only have a vague idea of what is going on. I want to know more of ALSA, PulseAudio, and especially squeezebox and squeezelite, so I welcome virtually any answer!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is about getting rid of that squeezelite blocks audio.

This was probably because squeezelite was directly using the ALSA device.

Solution for this: Specify the output device used by squeezelite.

```
squeezelite -o pulse
```

Btw all devices are listed with

```
squeezelite -l
```

Note: At least very recent versions (using here with 17.04: 1.8-3build1) use by default this output, i.e. '-o default' should be the same as '-o pulse'.